# Match string to specific pattern

Tags: vb.net

I would like my program to check for user input for a specific pattern. I've indicate using a label beside it that this particular TextBox1 must be in this format "XX/XX" (where as XX must be numeric ONLY and can have unlimited characters).

However there are no coding side checking to check for user input. Currently the solution I search in internet is using

```
Dim sMatch As Boolean
sMatch = TextBox1.Text Like "[0-9]/[0-9]"
```

The only problem is it only accept single digit of number. For example 5/4, what I want is a dynamic input for example 123/1 or 9/12 or 999999/30000. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there,

```
sMatch = TextBox1.Text Like "\d{1,}/\d{1,}"
```

or

```
sMatch = TextBox1.Text Like "[0-9]{1,}/[0-9]{1,}"
```

Good reference is from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

\d   Matches any decimal digit.
{n,} Matches the previous element at least n times

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use [Masked Text boxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in this scenario.

or you can try this also

```
Sub Main()
    Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]")
    Dim match As Match = regex.Match("x1/1x2")
    If match.Success Then
        Console.WriteLine(match.Value)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Does not match")
    End If
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```